# Java web start on iPad

Tags: java, ipad, ios, java-web-start

Can I run Java applications (Java Web Start) on iPad?

Looks like this is not possible, but someone suggested using Cloud Browse (an application I couldn't' find) to run Java.

Any solutions?

**UPDATE**: Cloud Browser is an application that **was** available on the App Store but it was removed my Apple. Cloud Browse would process the web site externally and then stream the web site content to your iPad screen (something like video streaming).

Comment: I voted to move this to superuser.com

Comment: are you trying to run an application or are you trying to develop an application?

Comment: @jzd I'm trying to run an existing application (jnlp)

Comment: @Michael Dillon, 10-4, I'll add this question to superuser.com, or is there an "automatic" way to migrate it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you cannot run Java programs on the iPad (or any iOS device). Apple's license terms forbid running applications that can execute code downloaded from the Internet (which is what Java Web Start is all about).

Answer (score 1):

No, as staffan said, Webstart will not work.  However using CloudBrowse, an applet can work.  It looks like the idea behind Cloud Browse is that the browser gets rendered on the server and video of the web page get streamed to your phone.  This way, it appears to the user that applets or flash are running on the ipad.

Answer (score 0):

I tried CloudBrowse on my IPAD as I've got a Java Applet that runs inside a brower and wanted it to work on my Ipad.

I found that it works pretty well. The Java Applet has a 3D animation, it's not as smooth as running on Windows/Mac through a normal web-browser, but it's pretty good.

I paid for full version, wasn't that expensive and to me, worth it. Opens up the power of using Applets but within Ipad!

Check it out [here](http://www.racemotion.com/demo.html) ... 3D sailing replay.